# Is there an easy way to find all the subset with a specific length of a list, using Python?

Tags: python, list, subset

If I have a list, say

```
a=[1,2,3,4]
```

I want to specify a length, let's say 3, then I can find all the subsets:

```
[[1,2,3],
[1,2,4],
[2,3,4]]
```

Does Python has a function so that I can do this quickly?

Comment: you can try **list(itertools.combinations(a, 3))**

Comment: You are missing (1, 3, 4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
import itertools
print(list(itertools.combinations(your_set, length_of_subsets)))
```